# TFS, deleting/undoing/check in blocked file

Tags: tfs, tfvc

We have created project with 3 ppl, but one of us had to leave company and left checked out file which is blocked. We cannot do anything with that so we decided to create new file with same funcionality. But how can we delete file he have blocked in TFS website. I would like to delete that file in Website TFS not via VS, Is it possible if so, how i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to undo pending changes from the website.

You can use the "undo other users changes" option from the commandline:

```
tf vc undo $/path/to/file /workspace:workspacename;username 
    /collection:https://server/tfs/collection
```

Given that you have the permission to do do (Project administrator should suffice).

You can also use the megablaster way to do this:

```
tf vc undo $/ /recursive /workspace:workspace;username
```

which will undo all pending changes across all projects in the colection.

To find the user's workspaces, use:

```
tf vc workspaces /owner:username
```

Comment: tf is not recognized as an internal or external command, what do I have to do to run it ( running on server machine where TFS is installed )

Comment: @d3nver Run it from a Visual Studio command prompt on a machine that has Visual Studio installed.

Comment: what if i don't have Visual studio ? We are using TFS for UiPath purposes without VS

Comment: I have deleted whole project, it was much faster than looking solution without VS, i know that it is not solution but still did the job.

Comment: :D. The alternative would have been to install Team Explorer Stand-alone. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer or using the Cross Platform Commandline Tools https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases